# Words or sentences can be used in IELTS Speaking Task2 A significant item

Tags: ielts

I am preparing for IELTS speaking task2. The cue card is:

[image]

After searching for a while on google, I want to say **time** is really significant to me. But I was stuck in diverse words and sentences.

My complete script is as follows:

Time is really significant to me. I got it when I was born and has possessed it for more than twenty years. (answer the first two questions)

(Justify why time is different). Life is divided into different stages by time and each phase is granted some tasks. For example, childhood gives people chance to enjoy happy playtime. Youth motivates people to decide their paths and pursue their dreams. Adult calls for sense of mission, letting people take their social and family responsibilities. Senior age is time for people to pass their experiences to the next generation and revive their dreams by guiding young people. In addition, human's energy changes with time.

Time is like a product that you cannot get refund. Whenever you like the day or not, once it is passed, you consumed it.

Now I enjoy my time, using it to study, communicate with wonderful people, and work. Some time may be wasted but the mercy of the God shows that with time, there is hope. And not until the end of the life, you will never guess what your life is like. Scarlet in the Gone With The Wind says tomorrow is another day. I want to say this second is another second.

My question is any useful words or sentences so that I can use when discussing this topic? Thank you!

Comment: Proofreading, even if it's supposed to represent a short speech, is off-topic. It clearly says so in the tag's description, which is why I did not suggest any corrections or improvements in my answer. However, I hope my answer did help you understand what is the aim of Speaking task 2. Good luck with the IELTS!

Comment: Please include the typed-out version of the card too, so it can be searched easily.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Not just that but also for when Imgur is not loading (because it’s not loading right now for me).

Comment: This really belongs on ELL.

Comment: You need to fix problems with _Adult, human's energy_, and _refund_. You are brave to choose time as "something you own."

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared candidates for the IELTS exam, and I am very familiar with these cue cards for speaking part two.

If you read the task carefully, it asks for something you **own**, this refers to a physical object that is in your possession.

By responding *time* I am afraid that the speaking examiner will think you have misunderstood the task.  I fully understand that *time* is a valuable resource, it is for everyone, but every living person has *time*. It is not something that you received as a birthday present nor is it something that you physically possess and could, one day, [gift](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/gift-as-a-verb) it to another person. In an essay or in a letter, it could be a really good idea, and you would have time to develop your ideas, but in the speaking exam, spontaneity and fluency is more prized.

On the day of the exam, you will only have a minute to jot down your answer and then you'll have to talk, uninterrupted, for about two minutes. The examiner will keep track of the *time* and when the two minutes are up, they will tell you to stop. It is therefore more important that you answer all three points within the two minutes allocated about an object that holds **[sentimental value](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sentimental-value)** than about abstract concepts. It's banal, I know, but examiners aren't really concerned with originality. They just want to hear you speak confidently about a familiar topic in English.

Comment: A very helpful response!

Comment: Some smart alec is going to post a comment saying that time is given to us the moment we are born, and it is a gift. I'm not disagreeing. Hi, @Shoe! I wasn't referring to you.

Comment: Time is a … Oh, wait. :P

Comment: Hi, your answer is illuminating. Although I practice kind of diligently, but this doesn't pay off in writing and speaking, which are like blackbox. Reading is kind to me(I got 9 in IELTS reading and GMAT 740/800, 97% globally). You answer tells me the exam rule matters. I am also looking for good proofreading tutor or community, if the price is suitable. I found one comment said here proofreading is off-topic unless specific source of concern is pointed. I guess my question "words regarding the topic" is still not specific.

Comment: @SharkDeng Hello. I'm glad the answer helped you understand better what the exam's aims are. The message re. proofreading means if you have a specific language problem, you are welcome to post a new question. P.S  What is a "blackbox"? Is it a blackbook? P.P.S. See meta for sites that offer free proofreading services https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571/where-can-i-ask-for-free-proofreading